# How do I perform multi-step forecasting on LSTM trained with multiple observations of a sequence?

Tags: rnn, lstm, forecast

I have a trained sequence-to-sequence LSTM that predicts a person's velocity trace (Δx, Δy) given their position (x, y) as they walk along a path. I trained the LSTM using 200 examples of different people walking along the path. Now, I would like to use multi-step forecasting to predict the future velocity of several new people after they have walked 1/3 of the path. Is this possible? If so, how can I implement this in Python or MATLAB?

Train = 200 sequence observations, 2 input features (x, y), time lengths of observations vary

Test = 5 partial sequence observations (1/3 of the sequence), I would like to predict the last 2/3 of the sequence for each person.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ConvLSTM, keras has an [implementation](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/#convlstm2d), therefore you can go with Python itself.

If you want multiple outputs from the LSTM, you can have look at `return_sequences` and `return_state` feature in `LSTM` layers. Default values for them are `None`, But if you give `True` you can get multiple outputs for each timestep, and for everyone.

This excellent blog [post](https://machinelearningmastery.com/return-sequences-and-return-states-for-lstms-in-keras/) helped me understand them.

Answer (score 0):

One technique is optical flow [1], [2], which is popular with people doing modeling of action videos.

There is a github implementation of [3] [here](https://github.com/viorik/ConvLSTM.), which she calls ConvLSTM, and is coded in Lua.

[1] P. Weinzaepfel, J. Revaud, Z. Harchaoui, and C. Schmid. Deepflow: Large displacement optical flow with deep matching. In Computer Vision (ICCV), 2013 IEEE International Conference on, pp. 1385–1392, Dec 2013. doi: 10.1109/ICCV.2013.175

[2] Philipp Fischer, Alexey Dosovitskiy, Eddy Ilg, Philip Hausser, Caner Hazirbas, Vladimir Golkov, Patrick van der Smagt, Daniel Cremers, and Thomas Brox. Flownet: Learning optical flow with convolutional networks. CoRR, abs/1504.06852, 2015

[3] Patraucean, V., Handa, A., & Cipolla, R. (2015). Spatio-temporal video autoencoder with differentiable memory. arXiv preprint arXiv:1511.06309.